# Web services testing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to create a windows form application that will test our ASP.Net web services. This application needs to test about 6 different service to be selected by a drop-down list. after the service is selected, the user will type in either a username or token. Then click a "test" button. The test results (the web service is working or not) should be displayed in a message box when the test is finished. The application should also test if any XML is returned and display that as well. I am a junior developer and know very little about web services. What is the best way to this testing tool? And where can I find a detailed tutorial with examples?

thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to deploy that application? If not then I suggest you look into unit testing instead, it would be far more efficient.

Comment: ...ask another developer on your team for help? ...

Comment: I'm with Simon, if you are a junior asking a senior member to provide you with some direction is not only helpful to you but also should be part of their role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good examples on CodeProject about how to consume WebServices.

[Here's an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8257/How-to-make-a-simple-WebService-and-consume-it)